# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: java, android

````
    Process: com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi, PID: 9900
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi/com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi.activity.MainActivity}: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{5e38638 u0a301 TPSL idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}**
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{5e38638 u0a301 TPSL idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)**}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1626)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1581)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:679)
        at com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:380)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)`your text`
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivity`your text`OnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
2022-11-30 10:06:23.297 9900-9979/com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-11-30 10:06:23.350 9900-9900/com.firstmile.taxicabondemandtaxi I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9900 SIG: 9```

```Im getting this error

this is my code```
````

Intent intent = new Intent(context, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
getApplication().startService(intent);

public static final String EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION = "com.paypal.android.sdk.paypalConfiguration";

Comment: You are trying to start your service when your app is not in foreground. Try making that service start as `startForeground` and making a notification so that the user knows a service is running.

Comment: Kindly format your code for proper reading and understanding. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You need to start foreground service instead of service

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
 } else {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
 }
```